# React-native: Project through error after update Catalina

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am facing issue in run the project after updating Mac OS version `high sierra` to `Catalina`

run command react-native init 
pod install in ios directory then run ios code using xcode(10.0)

> "react": "16.9.0"
>   "react-native": "0.61.3"

run ios code using xcode then ERROR is:-

error: error reading '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector/InspectorInterfaces.cpp'

Comment: Have you updated your cocoapods and xcode as well?

Answer (score 1):

Even I had faced this issue after updating to Catalina. 
Uninstall Xcode and restart your macbook. Then reinstall Xcode from AppStore. This worked for me.